# possible to run exe files in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a question, I made a Game Launcher for my Unity game with ReactJS, is it possible to run the game ( an exe file) when you click on play?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you should do it with NodeJS, as it will give you much more control. Invoke an API Call to your local NodeJS script

**ReactJS**

```
useEffect(() => {

   fetch(NODE_URL + "/execute-binary")
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => console.log(data));

}, []);
```

**Node Script:**

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var funToExecuteBinary = function(){
   exec('gamelauncher.exe', function(err, data) {  
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());                       
    });  
}

app.get('/execute-binary', function(req, res) {
    funToExecuteBinary();
    res.send('Game launcher executed');
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one more question: How can I add an update function? Like every time I start the launcher, the launcher check if there is a new version of the game.

Comment: Depends on how you are maintaining your version in the game? is it new exe file for every version ?

Comment: it is a new file

Comment: Might be not the best approach, you should use some sort of DB to maintain game version but if not you can rename the game .exe as a version like game_v1.exe and you should pass the latest version via API call from react to NodeJS so that the appropriate file can be loaded. If you find the answer above appropriate please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I dont use React for this project, but thanks